Missing user in SecurityContextHolder
I have created a field for user login, user data is taken from MySQL database. I am taken to a new window named /grid. In /grid, I have a "Save" button, which I want to use to save some data to the MySQL database. However, the problem is that when I press the "Save" button, I lose the logged-in user, and the method called by the button shows the user as "anonymous".
In the Vaadin session, I can see which user is logged in, but Spring loses it. Can anyone help me? Advise me on what I might be missing in my configuration? Perhaps there is a multithreading problem, but how can I deal with it effectively?
Here are the console logs:
User successful logged in: fish1
Logged user: fish1
Username while button is pressing in /grid: fish1
User in SecurityContext in class EnterProductService: anonymousUser  
User in VaadinSession in class EnterProductService: fish1

@Service public class EnterProductService {
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
public String urlForMapping = null;
public boolean enteredProductError = false;
public boolean reqOpenFoodFacts = false;
public boolean reqFoodDataCentral = false;
public String reqBarcode = null;
public MealType reqMealType = null;
public double reqGrams = 0;

private final Executor executor;

@Autowired
public EnterProductService(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") Executor executor) {
    this.executor = new DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor(executor);
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@Transactional
public void onSaveButtonClicked(String searchProductField, String gramAmount, MealType mealType) {

    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

    VaadinSession currentSession = VaadinSession.getCurrent();
    UI currentUI = UI.getCurrent();


    executor.execute(() -> {
        VaadinSession.setCurrent(currentSession);

        try {
            currentSession.lock();
            currentUI.access(() -> {
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
                System.out.println("User in SecurityContext in class EnterProductService: " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
                System.out.println("User in VaadinSession in class EnterProductService: " + VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute("username"));
                if (searchProductField != null && mealType != null && gramAmount != null) {
                    if (isOnlyNumeric(searchProductField)) {
                        reqBarcode = searchProductField;
                        reqGrams = Double.parseDouble(gramAmount);
                        reqMealType = mealType;
                        urlForMapping = String.format("/openfoodfacts/%s/%s/%s", searchProductField, gramAmount, mealType.name());
                        reqOpenFoodFacts = true;
                        reqFoodDataCentral = false;
                    } else if (isOnlyLetters(searchProductField)) {
                        reqBarcode = searchProductField;
                        reqGrams = Double.parseDouble(gramAmount);
                        reqMealType = mealType;
                        urlForMapping = String.format("/fooddatacentral/%s/%s/%s", searchProductField, gramAmount, mealType.name());
                        reqFoodDataCentral = true;
                        reqOpenFoodFacts = false;
                    } else {
                        enteredProductError = true;
                        reqOpenFoodFacts = false;
                        reqFoodDataCentral = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        } finally {

            currentSession.unlock();

        }

    });
}
public void sendRequestToApi() {
    String url = urlForMapping;
    String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/product" + url, String.class);

}

public boolean isOnlyNumeric (String string){
    return string.matches("\\d+");
}

public boolean isOnlyLetters (String string){
    return string.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
}

Here is my class where the user in SecurityContext is missing:
Here I call onSaveButtonClicked() and the user is still available:
saveButton.addClickListener(event -> {
            System.out.println("Username while button is pressing in /grid " + username);
            enterProductService.onSaveButtonClicked(
            searchProductField.getValue(),
            gramAmount.getValue(),
            comboBox.getValue());
            enterProductService.sendRequestToApi();

I attempted to handle multithreading by checking active sessions, but this doesn't seem to work.
What am I missing in my configuration? Why is my user being lost in SecurityContext but still available in the VaadinSession?
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Lazy UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/user", "/VAADIN/**", "/UIDL/**", "/HEARTBEAT/**", "/resources/**", "/websocket-client.js").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/grid").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/grid", true)
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
//                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }


This has something to do with the transactions, at PreAuthorize level the method succeeds to evaluate the role of the user? If so, the @Transactional method opened a new transaction, by default the Propagation is required, in the case no transaction is already open, then a new transaction will be opened, and, Spring Security context holder strategy is ThreadLocal by default, try setting it to InheritableThreadLocal as follows:
-Dspring.security.strategy=MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL

You find the user in the VaadinSession because it is  typical javax.servlet.http.HttpSession

currentSession.lock(); is not needed the UI.access(..) will handle locking of the session. I would also recommend not to set thread locals in thread pool. That is prone to reference leakage and security issues when threads from pool are re-used.

The problem is in the expression
.anyRequest().permitAll()

This code disables secured access to all your endpoints.
If you replace it with
.anyRequest().authenticated()

then Spring Security authorization will work.

Please stop revenge downvoting other people's answers. That is not mature behavior.

@BalusC What do you mean?

When i change to .authenticated() then my site /login is no more available. I get message that localhost server rejected the connection...

@SimiSimi I assume you haven't added a password authentication filter. Try not to make the AuthenticationManager bean. In this case, Spring Security should configure everything itself.
